# counting digits in a list of characters

Tags: haskell

I need to count how many digits appear in a list of characters using haskell.
eg. `['2','3','d','r','t','5']`
would output 3

I have managed to do it using string but cannot get it to work while using characters

this is my code for string

```
isNumber' :: String -> Bool
isNumber' s = case (reads s) :: [(Int, String)] of
[(_,"")] -> True
_         -> False

counta :: [String] -> Int 
counta = length . filter isNumber'
```

e.g. `['2','3','d','r','t','5']`
would output 3

Answer (score 2):

Since you say it is a list of characters, the type of `counta` should be:

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int 
counta = length . filter isNumber'
```

So that means that `isNumber'` has as signature `Char -> Bool`, and thus checks if a character is a digit. We however do not need to implement such function: in the `Data.Char` module, there is an [**`isDigit :: Char -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) function, so we can implement the `counta` with:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit)

counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta = length . filter isDigit
```

Comment: Do know how to do this using recursion

Comment: @g.s: try to make recursive functions for `length` and `filter` first. I think that will likely help you make a recursive function for `counta`.

Answer (score 1):

Not far off, but your `isNumber'` needs to take a character, not a string. So it would be of type

```
isNumber' :: Char -> Bool
```

Using `read` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`Char -> Bool` instead of `String -> Bool` and it should work without the read